# Zxing qr code decode can't get it work

Tags: c#, wpf, qr-code, zxing

I've searched all the forum and I cannot find the answer (and this is my first post, so sorry for possible errors).

I've downloaded Zxing pack and I would like to get the qr code decoder work (in c#, a WPF application). The problem is that I get no error while compiling, and the application goes well (I take the input stream from kinect rgb camera) but it seems it does nothing.

I report some code (probably I've made some error...):

```
 RGBLuminanceSource ls = new RGBLuminanceSource(bit, frame.Width,frame.Height);
 Result result = new QRCodeReader().decode(new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(ls)));
 if (result != null)
      Console.WriteLine("yahoo!");
 else
      Console.WriteLine("oh no");
```

with frame that is the frame captured by the kinect, and bit is the byte[] array that RGBLuminanceSource want as input, and I've made it by this:

```
byte[] bit= new byte[frame.PixelDataLength];
colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(bit);
```

What pass is that, when I put the paper with the qr code in front of the camera, it always return me the message "oh no", and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Any update? I have my (java) code running fine with video frames from my webcam, but keep getting checksum errors with the rgb image from kinect ...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the image which you get from the kinect camera is flipped.
You have to flip it back before decoding.
You can find some more detail here:
http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/discussions/401772

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that's not my problem...i've already read that forum and already have done the flip :( (in every possible way, meaning flipX flipY flipXY...) No one knows????:((

Comment: What is the value of the property "Format" of the colorFrame instance?

Comment: Just found out flipping was my issue (checksum error comment above).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles upon this question, There are few things you can check.

1. Download the QRCodeDecoder sample from ZXing git and have it at ready
2. Save your Bitmap file to a folder location.
3. Check whether the saved Image decodes correctly from the QRCodeDecoder.

If you are using this for a QR Code scanner via the webcam or other video source, check whether you are converting the bitmap image in the correct pixel format.

hope this helps